# Read multipart/mixed in C# (.NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, multipart

I get a multipart/mixed (with a JSON object and a file) like this, as response when I call a web service:

```
"--Boundary_9_15033478_1405613164044\r\n

Content-Type: application/json
\r\n\r\n{\"docId\":9007492,\"protId\":200,\"protNum\":\"0002084B14\",\"protDate\":\"Wed Jul 16 00:00:00 EEST 2014\",\"categoryId\":1000,\"desc\":\"ѥⷞ ��ƣ䲜��",\"linkNum\":\"ư1\\/00005545\",\"flag1\":\"\",\"flag2\":\"\",\"flag3\":\"\",\"flag4\":\"\",\"stsId\":1,\"stsDesc\":\"WS04: Check Layer I - OK\",\"wsDataList\":[],\"fileName\":\"WsTestToolkitMain.jpg\"}\r\n--Boundary_9_15033478_1405613164044\r\n

Content-Type: application/octet-stream
\r\n\r\n????\0JFIF\0\0`\0`\0\0??\0C\0\a\a\a\a\a\a\b\t\v\t\b\b\n\b\a\a\n\r\n\n\v\f\f\f
...
...
...
??\n?$??\0???????\r\n--Boundary_9_15033478_1405613164044--\r\n"
```

The way I got it is by getting a Stream of the response (of the HttpWebRequest) and then decode it with UTF-8. This gives me the above String. **The question is** how can I get the JSON and (more importantly) save **the file** ?

I tried changing (because they are for multipart/form-data not multipart/mixed) [this](http://antscode.blogspot.ie/2009/11/parsing-multipart-form-data-in-wcf.html) and [this](https://bitbucket.org/lorenzopolidori/http-form-parser/wiki/Home) but I can't get the file, maybe because its Content-Type is **application/octet-stream**  . Here is what doesn't work, file appears as it was damaged/corrupted in windows:

```
// Read the stream into a byte array
byte[] data = ToByteArray(stream);//Source
string content = encoding.GetString(data);
int contentLength = content.Length;//Length
byte[] fileData = new byte[contentLength];//Destination
Buffer.BlockCopy(data, startIndex, fileData, 0, contentLength);
this.FileContents = fileData;
File.WriteAllBytes("G:\\" + parser.Filename, parser.FileContents);
```

**UPDATE:**
Followed the answer by Anton Tykhyy (thanks!) but I'm getting an error when

```
var multipart = await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync () ;
```

**Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a content-type header value. 
'HttpContent' instances must have a content-type header starting with 'multipart/'.**

I tried to add this line before

```
content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed");
```

but now I'm getting another error (that I don't really understand too)

**Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a 'multipart' content-type header with a 'boundary' parameter.**

**UPDATE 2:**
Found it, I just had to do this:

```
    var content = new StreamContent(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", httpResponse.ContentType);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [ReadAsMultipartAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontentmultipartextensions.readasmultipartasync.aspx) in the [`System.Net.Http.Formatting` assembly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/), along the lines of

```
var content   = new StreamContent (stream) ;
var multipart = await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync () ;
foreach (var part in multipart)
{
    if (part.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json")
    {
        // deserialize via stream e.g. part.ReadAsStreamAsync () or via string
        // using part.ReadAsStringAsync () to avoid charset grief
    }
    else
    using (var file = File.Create (parser.Filename))
        await part.CopyToAsync (file) ;
}
```

This ought to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem (read the multipart that is), **but had to move to .NET 4.5** , if anyone knows the changes in order to work in **.NET 4.0** (by replacing "await" and "async" with something else I guess) I would love to know. So that's what I did.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

            //some code here...

            // POST the request
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Console.Write(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
            readMultipart(httpResponse).Wait();
    }

    async static Task readMultipart(HttpWebResponse httpResponse)
    {
         var content = new StreamContent(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", httpResponse.ContentType);
        var multipart = await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
        String filename = "";
        String json = await multipart.Contents[0].ReadAsStringAsync();
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
        filename = o["fileName"].ToString();
        using (var file = File.Create("C:\\testWS\\" + filename))
            await multipart.Contents[1].CopyToAsync(file);
    }
```

Comment: The simplest approach is just to replace `await` with `.Result`, although this blocks the thread. You might try targeting .NET 4.0 with the 4.5 compiler, because while code equivalent to compiler-generated `async/await` can be written manually using `.ContinueWith`, it is complicated and convoluted (which is why `async/await` was added to the compiler).